# Facebook iOS SDK 4.6 cannot changing loginBehavior

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk

In Facebook iOS SDK 4.6 
I tried using this code 
        loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        loginManager.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;

But still unable to make the login flow using native app. It just keep openning SafariViewcontroller.  Any workaround for this ?   TIA

Comment: I have the same trouble, only FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount are working...